# In Ruby on Rails, after "gem install <gem_name>", how to make it extend Array, or use its class method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler, natural-sort

Summary: after I `gem install <gem_name>`, how do I make it extend `Array` which the gem can do?

---

Details:

I see a gem for "natural language sort", which is

http://rubygems.org/gems/naturalsort
http://naturalsort.rubyforge.org/

so I am using Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.0.6, and I add the line

```
gem 'naturalsort'
```

into `Gemfile`, and do a `bundle install` and restart the server, but now, for some reason, I still can't do a

```
NaturalSort::naturalsort ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

in my helper file?  How can it be done?

Also, it would be nice to just extend array so it can be done by `arr.natural_sort`, but I have to add the line

```
require 'natural_sort_kernel'
```

to the beginning of the helper file.  The good thing is that it works, but it is a bit messy to have `require` every where.  Is there a way to make it work, possibly by also modifying the `Gemfile` or something else?

Comment: You can just add that line require `'natural_sort_kernel'` 
 to file called natural_sort_kernel.rb in config/initializers/

Comment: but in `config/initializers`, there is no file called `natural_sort_kernel.rb`... there are files such as `session_store.rb`... if I do `find . -name *natural*` in my Rails project folder it doesn't show any file

Comment: I tried also adding it to `config/environment.rb` -- adding `require 'natural_sort_kernel'` after the line that loads `rails`: `require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)` and it works too...  but what is a proper way...

Comment: You can simply create a file of your own called natural_sort_kernel.rb under config/initializers, rails will execute any files you put under that directory. Just put your require statement in that file and everything should work. That would be the best way in my opinion.

Comment: BTW, nathanvda's solution works too and it looks fairly elegant too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Gemfile` write

```
gem 'naturalsort', :require => 'natural_sort_kernel'
```

That should do the trick.

Hope this helps.

Comment: amazing! it works... how do you know that?  is it part of Bundler's docs?

Comment: Normally it is not needed, if the require name is the same as the gem-name. For some gems, as your example, you have to specify it explicitly. It is indeed in the bundler documentation: http://gembundler.com/man/gemfile.5.html

Comment: anyone know of a way to programmatically determine the require name, like from the gem's specification (anything in the rubygems Gem:: classes)?

Answer (score 1):

There is all so the following rail plugin

https://github.com/logandk/natural_sorting

Comment: so the plugin will automatically extend `Array`?  Can't the `gem` have similar ability?