# For Ruby on Rails, instead of adding "require '<gem_name>'" every where, is it good to add them all to config/environment.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In a Rails project, I see

```
require '<gem_name>'
```

in several files, some in controller, some in helper.  It is a little bit unorganized this way -- is it a good convention to put them all under `config/environment.rb` or is there any better ways?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

You need to do this in your Gemfile:

```
gem '<gem_name>', :require => '<gem_file>'
```

Comment: In cases like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711869/in-ruby-on-rails-after-gem-install-gem-name-how-to-make-it-extend-array-or  it won't work...

Comment: It will once you add the :require bit.